# Access items or controls of Main Page in the Child Page in UWP using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, uwp

A control button on MainPage loads another page onto a frame. This page is being used to get user login details. It has a LOGIN button. On successful login, I wish to show the USER NAME on a textblock in MainPage. I am unable to access the textblock in mainpage in the click event of the child page. 
How to go about?

Comment: Have your read about variable scope in .NET? This is a great starting point: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have basic understanding of variable scope. However, there might be something that I lack. I can pass and retrieve values from variables in my program.
However, I am unable to put those values in texblock in different page in my same app.
I have the title text block on mainpage and get the user login details in login page. if login is successful, I  wish to navigate user to a new page in a frame and show the logged in username on the mainpage. 
So I think I need to make my textblock public. But how to do that?